# How can I use a variable from a script?

Tags: bash, command-line, scripting, variable

A bash script is running as I defined it in Startup Applications. It is possible to display on terminal a variable used in that script? If yes, how?

Comment: You don't even tell us what kind of script? bash, Perl, Python? `echo "$var"`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging It's about a script bash. I tagged this thing.

Comment: It is rather unusual to use the tags for providing essential information rather than for a summary of the question's main topics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer (assuming this is a bash script as tagged) is no, variables are not shared between separate shell instances.  The only way I know of to access a variable from a script started in a different shell is to have the script write the variable to a file and then access that file.

Comment: Have a look at `/proc/$PID/environ` and be happy. (Yes, that works for exported variables only.)

Comment: @HaukeLaging doesn't seem to work. I have a script running that contains `export FOO=bar` and cannot see `FOO` in /proc/$PID/environ` (I tried both the script's PID and the PID of the shell the script is running in).

Comment: Sorry, then I had a misunderstanding about how `export` works. Seems it becomes active after a fork / before an execve only.